# How to conditionally change the static type of an object in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I’m trying to create an online store and having a hard time implementing a flexible form system that ideally should change depending on the type of item I add to the store.
For example, when choosing ‘Clothing’ category, the static type of the object created changes, and the form automatically morphs and deletes/creates all the necessary input fields.

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  category: string;
  price: number;
}

interface ClothingItem extends Item {
  size: string;
}

interface MonitorItem extends Item {
  resolution: string;
}
```

```
@Component({…})
export class ItemCreateComponent {
  item: Item;
  form = this.fb.group({
    category: [''],
    title: [''],
    price: [''],
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```

What I expect to happen is for the `item`’s type to change, for example, to `ClothingItem`, when a user selects ‘clothing’ category in the form, and `form` property adds missing form controls.

It was really difficult to formulate this question, and I truly hope that it was at least a bit clear to you.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to avoid `if` ternary operators and stuff, right?

Comment: You want dynamic forms, here is good article on how to do it. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: maybe this helps too: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/25/angular-8-dynamic-reactive-forms-example

Comment: @JefferinJoseph I'd be happy to implement it in any way other than hardcoding

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc maybe, but that article doesn't show how to make it work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (it's just an idea, I haven't tested it):

```js
@Component({…})
export class ItemCreateComponent {
  formFields: string[] = [];
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup();

  item: Item;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  buildForm(item: Item) {
    this.formFields = [];

    const obj = {};
    const keys = Object.keys(item).sort();
    for(const key of keys) {
     obj[key] = [''];
    }

    // The setTimeout is just to give time to angular change 
    // detection to destroy the form already present on the dom 
    // before switching to the new form shape. Otherwise, 
    // you could get an error for having, in the form template,  
    // HTML form elements different from the ones currently set  
    // on this.form object 
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.form = this.fb.group(obj);

      this.formFields = keys;
    }, 300);
  }
```

and in the template

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input *ngFor="let field of formFields" 
           [formControlName]="field">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your item to be interchangeable, the type of item should be `any`, not `Item` as this will only accept `Item` type objects.

If you want to check afterwards if your item has the correct type use

```
item instanceof yourDerivedItem
```

or

```js
const result = (item: any): item is yourDerivedItem => { return true }
```

Comment: The thing is I dont wan't to know the item's type. I want to change the item's type. In other words I don't want to check the type, but set it.